# How to know if a thread is finished in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Working on a Java project and I would like to know if a thread has finished the required calculations.

## First attempt: `done` variable in runnable

The first class is a manager

```
import uckochfractalfx.UCKochFractalFX;

public class KochManager {
    private final UCKochFractalFX application;
    private final IEdgeCollection edges;

    private int level;
    private int count;

    public KochManager(UCKochFractalFX application) {
        this.application = application;
        this.edges = new EdgeArrayList();
    }

    public synchronized void changeLevel(int nxt) {
        this.level = nxt;
        this.count = 0;
        this.edges.clear();

        EdgeGenerator left, right, bottom;
        left = new EdgeGenerator(this, EdgeLocation.LEFT);
        right = new EdgeGenerator(this, EdgeLocation.RIGHT);
        bottom = new EdgeGenerator(this, EdgeLocation.BOTTOM);

        Thread tLeft, tRight, tBottom;
        tLeft = new Thread(left);
        tRight = new Thread(right);
        tBottom = new Thread(bottom);

        tLeft.start();
        tRight.start();
        tBottom.start();

        while (!(left.isDone() && right.isDone() && bottom.isDone()) {
              wait();
        }

        this.application.setTextCalc(String.valueOf(this.totalTimeExecution));
        this.application.setTextNrEdges(String.valueOf(this.count));    
        application.requestDrawEdges();
    }

    public synchronized void addEdge(Edge edge) {
        this.edges.add(edge);
    }

    public synchronized void increaseCount() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getLevel() {
        return level;
    }

    public void drawEdges() {
        this.application.clearKochPanel();
        this.edges.getAll().forEach((Edge e) -> this.application.drawEdge(e));

        this.application.setTextDraw(String.valueOf(this.totalTimeExecution));
    }
}
```

And this is the EdgeGenerator class

```
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

public class EdgeGenerator implements Runnable, Observer {

    private final KochManager kochManager;
    private final EdgeLocation edgeLocation;
    private final KochFractal koch;
    private boolean done;

    public EdgeGenerator(KochManager kochManager, EdgeLocation edgeLocation) {
        this.kochManager = kochManager;
        this.edgeLocation = edgeLocation;

        this.koch = new KochFractal();
        this.koch.addObserver(this);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        koch.setLevel(kochManager.getLevel());
        this.done = false;

        switch (this.edgeLocation) {
            case LEFT:
                this.koch.generateLeftEdge();
                break;
            case RIGHT:
                this.koch.generateRightEdge();
                break;
            case BOTTOM:
                this.koch.generateBottomEdge();
                break;
        }
        this.done = true;
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object o1) {
        this.kochManager.addEdge((Edge) o1);
        this.kochManager.increaseCount();
    }
}
```

Everything works but one thing, and that is getting the values from the objects in the thread back to the main thread.

The variable I would like to focus on here is `done` in the `EdgeGenerator` class.

I have tried a couple of ways here.

First is the implementation as you can see it in the code above: Set `this.done` after all the calculations, which should then be returned by calling `isDone()`.
However when calling `isDone()` it always returns `false`

## Second attempt: `done` in caller of runnable

Then I decided to create a variable in `KochManager` called `leftDone`, create a setter `setLeftDone()` and call that in `EdgeGenerator`. This also always retuned false.

Manager:
    public class KochManager {
        private final leftDone;
        ...

```
    public void setLeftDone(boolean done) {
        this.leftDone = done;
    }
    ...  

    public synchronized void changeLevel(int nxt) {
        ...
        while (!(this.leftDone && this.rightDone && this.BottomDone)){
            wait();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

EdgeGenerator:

```
public class EdgeGenerator {
    ...
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        ...
        switch (this.edgeLocation) {
            case LEFT:
                this.koch.generateLeftEdge();
                this.kochManager.setLeftDone(true);
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

As you might have guessed that didn't work either, so after some more searching I decided to use another object that would have a single value.

## Third attempt: Create class `Done` that would hold a variable to be set.

Manager:

```
public class KochManager {
    private class Done {
        public boolean done;
    }
    ...

    private Done leftDone;

    public KochManager(UCKochFractalFX application) {
        this.application = application;
        this.edges = new EdgeArrayList();
        this.leftDone = new Done();
    }

    public void setLeftDone(boolean done) {
        this.leftDone.done = done;
    }
    ...  

    public synchronized void changeLevel(int nxt) {
        ...
        while (!(this.leftDone.done && this.rightDone.done && this.BottomDone.done)){
            wait();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

EdgeGenerator:

```
public class EdgeGenerator {
    ...
    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        ...
        switch (this.edgeLocation) {
            case LEFT:
                this.koch.generateLeftEdge();
                this.kochManager.setLeftDone(true);
                break;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Once this did not work out either I decided to call the help of StackOverflow.
Can someone help me out here?

Comment: The problem with your first approach is that `done` isn't volatile (and `isDone()` isn't synchronized), so the code isn't thread-safe and you might be getting a stale `false` value.

Comment: I would definitely recommend using something like `Future` with an `Executor` to handle this.

Comment: Do you understand what calling `wait()` does? Do you actually call `notify()`?

Answer (score 5):

> However when calling isDone() it always returns false

You need to go with Option-1, but mark your `done` variable as `volatile` as shown below, **otherwise the other threads will not be guaranteed to see the changes to the `done` variable**.

```
private volatile boolean done;
```

The following is the quote taken from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) about `volatile`

> Changes to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads.
>   What's more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile
>   variable, it sees not just the latest change to the volatile, but also
>   the side effects of the code that led up the change.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you have one of the common gotchas with concurrency: memory visibility. When one thread updates *done* the others don't see it has been updated. You must declare you *done* variable as volatile in order to prevent this issue from happening:

```
volatile boolean done;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the value of `done` is cached. You need to mark it as `volatile` so that calls to it from various threads always get the most up-to-date value.